# How to create a pydicom Tag from its name?

Tags: python, pydicom

Is it possible to create a Tag (pydicom.tag.Tag) only from its name? For instance, 'Rows' is associated to (0028,0010). Creating a Tag for it would be:

```
tag=pydicom.tag.Tag(0x28,0x10)
```

I would like to create the same tag from its name, like

```
tag=pydicom.tag.Tag('Rows')
```

which is not working.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do it? Or equivalently, is there a function to find the number of a tag from its name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: As of pydicom 1.3, can now create a Tag instance using the keyword, e.g.

```
>>> from pydicom.tag import Tag
>>> Tag("Rows")
(0028, 0010)
```

---

Original answer:

In the DICOM standard, the tag 'name' is properly called a 'keyword'.  The [`tag_for_keyword` method](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/api_ref.html#pydicom.datadict.tag_for_keyword) in pydicom.datadict that does what you are asking:

```
>>> from pydicom.datadict import tag_for_keyword
>>> from pydicom.tag import Tag
>>> tag_for_keyword("Rows")  # just as a number, not a Tag instance
2621456
>>> tag = Tag(tag_for_keyword("Rows"))
>>> tag
(0028, 0010)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!